# Rendering radio buttons

Tags: javascript, virtual-dom, maquette

How do I properly define radio buttons using [Maquette](http://maquettejs.org/) so the text will render? If I use a `<p>` element the text appears, but on a new line.

```js
var h = maquette.h;
var dom = maquette.dom;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var form = h("form", [
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "5", name: "freq"}),
      h("p", ["5 Hz"]),
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "10", name: "freq"}),
      h("p", ["10 Hz"]),
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "15", name: "freq"}),
      h("p", ["15 Hz"]),
   ]);
  document.body.appendChild(dom.create(form).domNode);
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maquette/2.4.1/maquette.min.js"></script>
```

However, if I use a `<br>` element, the text doesn't appear.

```js
var h = maquette.h;
var dom = maquette.dom;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var form = h("form", [
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "5", name: "freq"}),
      h("br", ["5 Hz"]),
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "10", name: "freq"}),
      h("br", ["10 Hz"]),
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "15", name: "freq"}),
      h("br", ["15 Hz"]),
   ]);
  document.body.appendChild(dom.create(form).domNode);
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maquette/2.4.1/maquette.min.js"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You know that `br` is an empty element (an element that cannot have text node), don't you? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: `<br/>` tags are standalone, they don't render text. and `<p>` tags are `display: block` so they render on separate lines. Try using a `<span>` tag or something.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I did not know this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the `<br>` tag. Generally, it is used as an empty, self-closing tag (either `<br>` or `<br/>`). [You can read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br), *Permitted content - None, it is an empty element.*

You can place the text in an inline element like a `<span>` or event better with `<label>`, using `id` on the input and `for` attribute on the label. Then, place an empty `<br>` after each row to separate the different radio buttons.

Here is the solution itself:

```js
var h = maquette.h;
var dom = maquette.dom;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var form = h("form", [
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "5", name: "freq", id: "freq1"}),
      h("label", {innerHTML: "5 Hz", "for": "freq1"}),
      h("br"),
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "10", name: "freq", id: "freq2"}),
      h("label", {innerHTML: "10 Hz", "for": "freq2"}),
      h("br"),
      h("input", {type: "radio", value: "15", name: "freq", id: "freq3"}),
      h("label", {innerHTML: "15 Hz", "for": "freq3"}),
   ]);
  document.body.appendChild(dom.create(form).domNode);
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/maquette/2.4.1/maquette.min.js"></script>
```